# Enable Jailshell Access from Command Line

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

There is an option in whm/cpanel to enable jailshell access for any hosting account.

I want to know if it is possible to enable that option for any or all cpanel hosting accounts through command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jailshell can be enabled for a user in **WHM** by navigating to *Manage Shell Access* under *Account Functions*.

To setup jailshell access for a user from the command line interface, simply use the operating system's change shell command as root, for example:

```
# username=CPANELUSERNAME;
# chsh -s /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell ${username}
```

You may also be interested in these sections of cPanel's documentation:

- [VirtFS (Jailed Shell)](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/VirtFS), which describes how to provision Jailshell.
- [Creating Custom Jailed Shell (Jailshell) Mounts](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/CreateCustomMounts), which describes how to setup customized mounts for use within jailshell.

---

**Remember:**

`${username}` and `$username` both refer to a local variable called `username`.

Suppose your username is `fahad`.

If you want to change the shell without using the variable, it would look like this:

```
# chsh -s /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell fahad
```

If you typed `chsh -s /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell ${username}` without setting the variable `username` first, it would be equivalent to `ch -s /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell` without any parameter after to designate the user whose shell you want to change, and then the command defaults to changing the shell for the currently logged in user.

**You also said that you're getting this error:**

```
 '0' is not a valid user id, and may not run jailshell (cpanel users file missing).
```

That is caused because the root account has been set to use jailshell, though it should not be. This could have happened when you executed the above command without passing the parameter for the user account (i.e. by using an unset variable).

You may wish to reset your shell to `/bin/bash` in **WHM** by navigating to *Manage Shell Access* under *Account Functions*. Alternatively, if you are comfortable doing so, you can edit the change is in the `/etc/password` file manually by running `vipw` (as the file cannot be edited directly easily under most systems).

Comment: I have tried from root user chsh -s /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell ${username} 

replaced {username} to {my cpanel user name} but it changed my root to jail shell. Now when I login by root id it gives me this error '0' is not a valid user id, and may not run jailshell (cpanel users file missing).
and also I am getting this prompt -jailshell-4.1#

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have created a ticket on my hosting support regarding this issue but they are saying ""This broke root. Using this command improperly from the command line has caused root to be put into a jailed shell. The only way to restore this is to do a vps restore.""
Is there any way we can restore root user shell access to normal without restoring the VPS ??

Comment: If your VPS provider supports it, you may be able to reboot the VPS into single user mode or using a recovery kernel.

Comment: Someone in your position was able to recover via [SU mode](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1047179).

Comment: This worked for me chsh -s /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell fahad
just want to know if we can similarly use this for noshell and normalshell ??

Comment: Yes absolutely. Just put the path to the shell binary in place of the jailshell binary path.

Comment: Just one last question, what will happen if we put wrong cpanel username in this command chsh -s /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell fahad will that brake the root shell or simply giv any error ??